# Approach to load testing a Geolocation iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, testing, load

I created an iOS app in Swift, and utilized Firebase Auth and DB for the backend. I can't get super detailed on the specifics, but it involves Geolocation services, and is similar (although much simpler) to Uber/Lyft. Both drivers/riders share the same app. You have to click on a another button to get to the driver interface.

I need to create a simulation where multiple virtual users (both drivers/riders) are using the application at the same time (I would like to measure success/failure of each action, as well as response time). I don't need to randomize the simulation, but I do have to account for the fact that there is an interaction between two users. In other words, it's not the usual performance test where you log-in, view profile, update profile, log-out, etc. There is a dependence on one part of the test to complete before the other can start.

I'd like to see if I could get any ideas on the best approach to handle this. I can provide more details/context, if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something called bluepill https://github.com/linkedin/bluepill, but it is only used to launch simultaneous XCTest cases and Simulators, it doesn't guarantee the order of the tests, so it won't work for you

You can create UI tests and run them on two different macs, but you need to figure out how test are going to interact and it seems difficult.

**I would suggest to use**   `-only-testing` feature of the xcodebuild

You can create a UI Test Target for Rider and Another Test target for Driver and then use the `-only-testing` flag for xcode tests.

If tests are dependent on each other you can do

```
-only-testing:RiderUITests/Test1
-only-testing:DriverUITests/Test1

-only-testing:RiderUITests/Test2
-only-testing:DriverUITests/Test2
```

You get the idea.

Basically, you can write a script or use `fastlane` https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane and run only one test at a time, one by one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I gave you best answer. I need some way to calculate metrics and response time, so I'm not sure if bluepill will work, but will check it out anyway, since it looks interesting.